# Ejecutar comando cmd desde Laravel process

Tags: laravel, cmd

Intente ejecutar un commando `cmd` desde laravel utilizando la siguiente instrucción

```
$process = new Process('UiRobot -file "C:\Users\Renato\Documents\UiPath\EliminarPaciente\Main.xaml"');

$process->run();
```

Pero no me funciona, me podrian guiar porfavor

Comment: que hace el main.xaml, que necesitas hacer con ese comando... ya probaste el comando directamente en el equipo

Comment: Ya logre solucionarlo muchas gracias!

Comment: hola me puedes decir como lo solucionaste?